# SMS Stuck at Sending

Tags: sms

I have a very peculiar problem on my Android [Samsung Galaxy 5(five)].
Every time I send a text message, it is stuck at 'Sending...' and can be stuck on that for days until it shows that it has failed to send the message.
Sometimes I send 3 messages at a go and they end up being sent. Sometimes even this does not work.

What could be the problem? What can I do to rectify?
Desperate!

Comment: Can happen due to low network signal or problems in messaging number. Have you tried a different SMS app just to see if it works better?

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me, I disable the data on the device and re-enable it and the message usually goes through. You can also just try switching to airplane mode and then turn off airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes. I believe its a bug with the messaging app. I used to have this. I suggest force closing the application (Settings -> Manage Application -> Messaging -> Force Stop)

Once done, just reboot for safe measure. This should fix your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem on my LG Android handset, but then I realized that I hadn't done my 'SMS cleanup' for the last 6 months. I deleted all old messages, then things started working fine! It turned out to be a basic maintenance issue.